# Saving generated image data to Google Cloud for direct public access by URL

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

## Scenario

I have an application that accesses App Engine. This applications purpose is to show a custom map in a Google Maps object. This object expects individual map tiles to be available for specific levels of zoom.

The map will be generated daily, automatically.

## The problem

How can I save these individual tile images so that they can be called from the client(s) when they are needed?

I checked Google Cloud Storage. However, it looks like each tile would need to be individually set free and given a generated name to access it. It is important to be able to provide a URL with 3 integers (zoom, x, z) to access each image.

Comment: Wouldn't, just encoding the 3 integers in the tile's filename following a simple rule (which can be easily replicated on both the server and client side) be sufficient? Something like `tile_<zoom>_<x>_<z>.png`, for example? Unless I misunderstand your question...

Comment: I thought that the file identifier would be non-deterministic. Perhaps I am wrong. For example like Google Drive.

Comment: In GCS you control the file names: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/key-terms#object-names

Comment: Ahh! I must have missed that. OK, that is likely to be the easiest option for me. Thanks.